# Unhide the menu bar for app after compiled with electron-packager

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I notice that electron-packager has hide the top menu bar after we compiled an exe file if compared to electron-prebuilt. Is there ways to unhide it? I need to use it for user to choose some settings.

Same topic reference:
[github](https://github.com/maxogden/electron-packager/issues/199)

Answer (score 1):

You tried some like this?

```
mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(true);
```